# Is there a C/C++ API for reading CPU performance monitoring counters (PMC) on WIndows (for intel and AMD processors)?

Tags: c++, c, api, cpu, perf

Is there a C/C++ API for reading CPU performance monitoring counters (PMC) on WIndows (for intel and AMD processors) ?

What I have found so far :

1. https://icl.utk.edu/papi/
   Very good API but does not seem to support MS Windows
2. https://www.agner.org/optimize/#testp
   Supports Windows but has limited API features and requires cumbersome workflow with
   the PMC drivers "Disable Driver Signature Enforcement"

Surprisingly not even the AMD developer resource site does seem to provide a C/C++-API for reading AMD CPU performance cpounters (or am I overlooking somethimg ?)

**EDIT:** Found this related info:
https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2015/09/24/etw-central/

Comment: Try looking for profiler instead of performance.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/

Comment: -cup: The question is specifically about a API/library and not about profiling tools

Comment: Kernel support is required for programming HW counters.  And to have counters per user-space task (rather than for anything on a logical core), you'd also need kernel support to save/restore counters on context switches, like Linux does to support PAPI.   I'd guess there might be libraries with a kernel driver you could use on Windows, but there doesn't seem to be any standard one.  On Linux, you can use libraries other than perf/PAPI, too, e.g. lighter-weight kernel modules that just let you program counters on a core and use `rdpmc` in user-space.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: Thanks for the comment. Actually it would be sufficient for my purposes to have the counters on a per-physical-core basis (as i'm pinning threads to cores in the most time critical loops).

Answer (score 3):

The Windows kernel has built-in support to collect core PMC counters. This support is in the form of a kernel ETW event provider.

Typically, you would enable ETW providers and specify the OS write the event data to either a memory buffer or file. There are documented APIs and tools to ingest ETW trace files. Windows comes with a tool called Windows Performance Recorder wpr.exe that takes an XML configuration file (which is documented), and can handle the whole process of getting events into a ETW log file. For PMC counters, you would specify another event type like a profile timer tick or a thread context switch, and set options to attach your selected PMC counters to those events. A stack walk can also be attached to events which is needed to generate things like flame graphs. You also can have an event written when the PMC counter overflows and set the overflow interval, see the PerfView source code.

The OS comes with a tool, logman, that can convert an ETW log file into a XML file, which you can then parse with whatever XML tools you want. Logman is handy for small traces but causes like a 15:1 expansion of the trace size when converting the binary ETW log to XML, so is not so good for large traces. There is also a .Net class library that can do sophisticated decoding of ETW logs, search for Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent on nuget. The sources are also in PerfView.

There are native APIs to decode ETW traces, and there also are some Python libraries.  Using the native ETW control and sink APIs, it should also be possible to create a real-time trace session that consumes the PMC events, although the exact format of the option structures is poorly (or not at all) documented for enabling PMC counters. There are some hints in the C# sources for the PerfView tool on Github.

The OS comes with a basic set of generic PMC counter types, but you can also add CPU specific types either with a registry or as part of the WPR control file.

All of this is just user-mode code, the kernel mode part is already part of the OS on both x64 and ARM64 platforms.

The easiest path to something functional is likely create an wpr control file, use wpr to collect the data, and convert it to XML with logman.